# AJAX POST is not receiving correct value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to post the value of a selected radio button but the $_POST variable in PHP is getting assigned 'undefined', what do I need to change so the $_POST gets the correct value? I was thinking it might be because I havent used URIencode but when I do use this my JavaScript doesn't even get the element.

JAVASCRIPT

```
function rappoll(){
    var xmlHTTPreq;
    var url = "poll.php";
    var params="name="+name;
    var elements = document.getElementsByName("elements");
    var checkedButton = getName(elements);

if (checkedButton) {
    var name = checkedButton.value;
}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    try {
        xmlHTTPreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch(e) {
        xmlHTTPreq = false;
    }
} else {
    try{
        xmlHTTPreq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }catch(e){
        xmlHTTPreq = false;
    }
}

xmlHTTPreq.open("POST", url, true);
xmlHTTPreq.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(xmlHTTPreq.readyState == 4 && xmlHTTPreq.status == 200){
        document.getElementById('poll').innerHTML = xmlHTTPreq.responseText;
    }
}
xmlHTTPreq.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHTTPreq.send(params);

}

function getName(group){
for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
    var button = group[i];
    if (button.checked) {
        return button;
    }
}
return undefined;
```

}

PHP

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Comment: How do you know you get 'undefined'? If that is all your PHP code, it doesn't echo anything.

Comment: I used var_dump but didn't see any point in posting that @putvande

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare and assign `params` here:

```
var params="name="+name;
```

Since `name` is not defined `params` is now `"name=undefined"`. Note that `name` is *declared* because of variable hoisting, so you wont see `undefined variable 'name'`.

Once you assign `name` you must reassign `params` too, or change this line:

```
xmlHTTPreq.send(params);
```

to

```
xmlHTTPreq.send("name=" + name);
```